# Как сделать корректную передачу данных в get-запросе?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

При submite передается запрос http://site.ru/search/?area=kalininsky на выходе нормальный список, при http://site.ru/search/?area=leninsky, также.
Но как объединить данные запросы, чтобы выводился общий результат???

Пробовал: http://site.ru/search/?area=kalininsky&area=leninsky, но на выходе, то что в конце адреса (area=leninsky)

Comment: `area[]` попробуй в качестве имени параметра

Comment: помогло! не скажете каким, образом формировать именно такой get-запрос при выборе нескольких checkbox-ов?

Comment: Как вариант: собирай значения нужных чекбоксов в массив, и затем просто по нему нужную строку сформировать

Comment: `name="area[]"` вероятно.

Comment: @Visman, ну это смотря как запрос отправляется